# Frame creator method

Tags: java, methods, frame

I am trying to make a frame pop up with a scary image on it. I am asking a question using the JOptionPane and if they say that they are easily scared it pops up an image of a clown or something for example.
The problem is that when I try to make a method to create a JFrame it wont work. When I try to call the method it does not work. 
Here is the code

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Boo {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int x = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Do you consider yourself 
easily scared?",null,JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if(x == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){    
    String fileString = 
"C:\\Users\\20jdominiecki\\Downloads\\68b8a6e159169897cc01d8d34d184962.jpg";
    frameCreator();
    }
    int y = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Like what you 
see?",null,JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if (y == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
    {
    String fileString = "C:\\Users\\20jdominiecki\\Downloads\\doggo.jpg";    
    frameCreator();    
    }
}    
public void frameCreator(String fileString) throws IOException{

    File file = new File(fileString);
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.getContentPane().add(label);
    f.pack();
    f.setLocation(0,0);
    f.setVisible(true);


}

}
```

Comment: what u exactly want? what is an issue? it is working correctly after argument passed in my system

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you create the JFrame in the Method and once it's done the JFrame gets deleted.
Try this.

```
JFrame f;
    public void frameCreator(String fileString) throws IOException{

    File file = new File(fileString);
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
    f = new JFrame();
    f.getContentPane().add(label);
    f.pack();
    f.setLocation(0,0);
    f.setVisible(true);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for the inconvenience. I was not properly calling the method. I was not putting the string that was going into the method in the parenthesis when calling the method. I fixed this by calling the method with frameCreator(fileString);

Sorry guys!